# Fake space between First and Last Name in excel

Tags: formatting, excel-2010, spacing

I have a spreadsheet that I have imported from one of our sites that we use for User Access.  I am having trouble in the formatting of the spreadsheet in order to make it searchable and to use VLOOKUP.  In the Full Name column, the first and last name look like they are separated by a space " " but it does not work that way when I try to split them into First Name and Last Name columns.  It is almost like it is a fake space.  I have tried many ways to make it a true space between the words but nothing has worked and none of my researching to find a solution to this problem has been found.  Can anyone help me with figuring this out so I don't have to continue to delete the "fake space" and add a real space between the words?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you doing to split the name and in what way is it not working?

Comment: I am using the formulas:=Trim(LEFT(B638,FIND(" ", B638))) and =Trim(RIGHT(B638,LEN(B638)-FIND(" ",B638))) to split up the Full Name Column.  But it does not work with the current spacing

Comment: Can you post a sample workbook somewhere that contains one of these values?

Comment: Where could I post it to?

Comment: Dropbox, OneDrive, Google Drive, wetransfer.com, etc. As long as it is public and I can download it to check it out.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3hjbje5l79q47aa/Sample%20-%20Full%20Name%20issue.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I tried that and it still does not work.

Comment: I tried it with the spreadsheet you posted to Dropbox and it worked. Not sure what else to offer without some more details.

Answer (score 0):

These are [non-breaking spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). I am guessing that this data is coming from an HTML source.

You can get your formulas to work by changing `" "` to `CHAR(160)`, which will return the non-breaking space (ASCII code 160).